# Why do you need to call super class inside constructor?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-beam

I appreciate if someone could help me understand the code example in below question. I am now trying to implement similar thing using `apache beam 2.13.0` with `python3.7.3`.

[Why does custom Python object cannot be used with ParDo Fn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55822881/why-does-custom-python-object-cannot-be-used-with-pardo-fn)

I have understood that `network sockets` are not serializable since it is not objects that could return neither *string* nor *tuple* after the serialization.

What I did not understand was why do you need to call `super class` inside `__init__` ?

```
class PublishFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, topic_path):
        self.topic_path = topic_path
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

    def process(self, element, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(self, 'publish'):
            from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
            self.publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
        future = self.publisher.publish(self.topic_path, data=element.encode("utf-8"))
        return future.result()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class inherits from `beam.DoFn`. Presumably that class needs to set up some things in its `__init__` method, or it won't work properly. Thus, if you override `__init__`, you need to call the parent class's `__init__` or your instance may not function as intended.

I'd note that your current `super` call is actually subtly buggy. It's not appropriate to use `self.__class__` as the first argument to `super`. You either need to write out the name of the current class explicitly, or not pass any arguments at all (the no-argument form of `super` is only valid in Python 3). Using `self.__class__` might work for now, but it will break if you subclass `PublishFn` any further, and override `__init__` again in the grandchild class.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the `__init__` method of the parent class does some initialization which is required for the class instance to function properly. If you *don't* call this method, your code will likely break because the class won't be properly initialized.

The `__init__` method of the parent class *is not* called automatically when you override that method in the child class (it works in the same way for other methods), so you need to call it explicitly.