# Can we import data in apache-beam using FTP?

Tags: ftp, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, ftps

I am writing a dataflow job using Apache-Beam which requires to import data in BigQuery using the FTPS [from ftplib import FTP_TLS] server. But the moment I try to import FTPS Class [ftps = FTP_TLS('ftp.xxxxx.xxx')], I get the error as "TypeError: can't pickle SSLContext objects".
I try to put the package in setup.py, to import ftplib package, but still the same error persists.

Does Apache-Beam not support data from FTPS server and if it supports then how to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because you didn't provide a code snippet.
But i think that you create your FTP_TLS object in the *init*.
All objects that are created in the init must be serializable.

You can try to create the object in the Process function.
For more details see: [see Ankur answer on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55824287)

More info see the documentation:

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#requirements-for-writing-user-code-for-beam-transforms